# SSRS 2008 "Unknown Collection Member" Error

Tags: reporting-services

This is driving me nuts. I added a column to a DataSet in my SSRS Report. I refreshed the fields and now the column displays in SSRS.

I want to place the value of this in a TextBox.

1. I added TextBox to the report
2. I right click the TextBox and pick "Expression"
3. In the dialog box I click Datasets --> MyDataSet --> First(MyNewColumn)

The results in the expression in the SSRS TextBox being

```
=First(Fields!MyNewColumnName.Value, "MyDataSet")
```

I then get a red squiggly line and an error that says "Unknown Collection Member". This is a lie, because it is part of the collection. I have verified that this value is returned when I run my query in SQL2008. When I preview the report I get "#Error"

Does anyone know what the real problem is here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the .data file, which I believed forced SSRS to rebuild it. After this happened, the report worked as expected.

Comment: What if I have no .data file to delete? (Or where should I look... there are none in the project's directory.)

Comment: The .data file should be located in your project folder. For example: _C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyReport\MyReport_